# Disable GridView AlternateRows

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I currently got a GridView containing several textvalues from which several transform into DropDownLists upon clicking Edit. This requires me to access the current Textvalue of a Cell and set the SelectedIndex of the DropDown accordingly after clicking Edit. This works for ... well, half the rows since only those have the RowStyle "Edit", the others have "Alternate | Edit" which is a nuisance since I don't really require that feature.

Here's my Code:

```
protected void gridVariables_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //this only works at RowIndex 0, 2, 4 etc.
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        switch (((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row.ItemArray[2].ToString())
        {
            case "True":
                ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[1]).Checked = true;
                break;
            case "False":
                ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[1]).Checked = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        ((DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[1]).Items.FindByValue(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row.ItemArray[3].ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

The GridView consists of TemplateFields which have Labels in the ItemTemplate and either a CheckBox (index 0) or DropDownList (index 3) as EditItemTemplate, the others are "normal" BoundFields. For some reason I feel unable to post the asp-markup without completely destroying the formatting of this post.

So, is there any way to either improve my programming structure to let it work with both "Edit" and "Edit | Alternate" rows or to disable the Alternating Rows Feature?

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataControlRowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowstate.aspx) is flags based enumeration, so correct way to write the condition would be

```
if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
```

Note *bitwise &* operator - it will work for both normal as well as alternate rows.

Comment: Thanks, this works just great! Will accept your answer as soon as I can.